# Getting all Inputs from an Array of Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently revisiting an old function, where I had a registration form consisting of several 'slides'. For the user to be able to proceed to the next slide the Input fields had to be validated (from that specific div).

eg.:

```
function validateForm() {
  //var curentSlide = 0;

  var divs, inputValues, validator = true;
  divs = document.getElementsByClassName("regWindow");
  inputValues = divs[currentSlide].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (let i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) { ... }
```

But now I have read that all JavaScript SHOULD be done with jQuery. I have managed to get the array of Divs by writing: `divs = ($(".regWindow"));`

But how do I now get all the Inputs from one Div? Thank you!

Comment: `I have read that all JavaScript SHOULD be done with jQuery` Wherever you read that was completely wrong. This is not the case *at all*.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript... so what you can do with JQuery you can do with JavaScript...

Comment: So... there is no advantage in rewriting that to jQuery?

Comment: There is only one advantage that dealing with JQuery is somewhat very easy as compared to vanilla js. But to have this advantage, you are also loading Jquery library. So its upto u.

Comment: `So... there is no advantage in rewriting that to jQuery?` Not intrinsically, no. If you have working JS logic, you are fine to leave it as it is. The only times a refactor to jQuery would be worthwhile is if you have multiple scripts in different frameworks and want to unify them, or if as a team, you want to update the framework being used for ease of development. In terms of native JS vs jQuery vs other frameworks, each have their own advantages.

Answer (score -1):

```
var divs = $(".regWindow");
for (var index=0; index< divs.length; index++ ) {
  var input = divs.eq(index).find("input");
  for(var item; item< input.length; item++) {
     console.log(input.eq(item));
  }
}
```

Comment: `divs[index].find("input")` This will cause an error

Comment: Typos, and then mix of jQuery and vanilla JS might be confusing.

Comment: That just leaves the redundant use of two loops,

Comment: To get input inside each div you will need to run two loop one loop per div and other for all inputs

Comment: This will _not_ work: `dives.length`. Why not create a demo in a snippet so you can iron out these errors.

Comment: Maybe help you if you get divs and div with child input seperately like this   divs = ($(".regWindow"));
  inputValues = ($(".regWindow :input"));